# Writing in memory buffer to S3 object directly via GO SDK for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a buffer that say when reaches 'X' number of records, it writes a file to disk. I can do a `PutObject` and send this to S3 and the object will exist this way. Is there a better more optimized way where I flush the in-memory buffer without writing to local disk directly to an S3 object?

Comment: Are you wanting to _append_ to the Amazon S3 object, or simply create a _new_ object? You can certainly create objects from memory rather than having to upload a file from disk.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need to create and that must be sufficient. Please tell me how is that possible? Additionally, I want to know if Append is possible as well since you touch upon it. I have a golang slice that when reaches a size, u hint that it is possible to directly send it to s3. Share how please

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 objects are immutable. It is not possible to 'append' to an S3 object.

However, some people get quite creative and the use the **multi-part upload** capabilities to keep sending new 'parts' of an object. The object is only finalized when a final command is sent that tells S3 to combine all the parts into one object. However, it would need some clever error handling in case something goes wrong before the multi-part upload is finalized, so my recommendation is to probably avoid this method.

When creating an object in S3, you can provide `bytes` as the `Body` rather than needing to upload a file.

Here is an example from [golang s3 PutObject](https://gist.github.com/CarterTsai/47f732121b34399d13fbd5765b3e11ed):

```golang
 params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
  Bucket: bucket,  // Required
  Key:    keyname, // Required
  ACL:    aws.String("bucket-owner-full-control"),
  Body:   bytes.NewReader([]byte("PAYLOAD")),
  ContentLength: aws.Int64(7),
 }
 resp, err := svc.PutObject(params)
```

Comment: Thanks. One dumb questons. I have a custom struct `type Mystruct struct {field: string, field2 int}`. How do I convert it to bytes.NewReader?

Comment: I'm not a Go person, so I can't assist. The answer would be to send it however you want the bytes to appear in the file, so I guess that depends on how you are going to _use_ the file.